# Facebook PHP SDK 4.0 : Getting Long Term Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, version, token

I'm trying to use the PHP sdk v4.0 to get a long term access token for PAGE management.

I'm grabbing the access token from the user's login (Yes, I'm grabbing the Page-specific access token). Then sending it to the endpoint as specified in documentation, but I'm not getting any results and I'm not getting any errors.

Could I know what is the correct code snippet to use?

This is the code I'm using so far

```
$endpoint   =   '/oauth/access_token?';
$endpoint   .=  'grant_type=fb_exchange_token&';
$endpoint   .=  'client_id='.$this->app_id.'&';
$endpoint   .=  'client_secret='.$this->app_secret.'&';
$endpoint   .=  'fb_exchange_token='.$access_token;

try {

    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
        $this->session, 'GET', $endpoint
    ))->execute();

    // Do something with the response here but response is empty

} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {

    echo $ex->getMessage();

} catch (\Exception $ex) {

    echo $ex->getMessage();

}
```

Comment: How are you getting `$this->session`?

Comment: Hi SammyK, actually was reading your blog earlier on handling access tokens! Would like if you could give me some hints.

I am generating the session via the facebook SDK
$this->session = new FacebookSession($access_token);

Comment: Sure! I'll submit a formal answer in just a bit. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There a several [types of access tokens](https://www.sammyk.me/access-token-handling-best-practices-in-facebook-php-sdk-v4) you can use with calls to Graph. Knowing which access token to use can be tricky.

## User Access Token

If you want to make changes to the page and post on the page wall as the admin user, you'll need to use that user's access token.

### Login

You'll need to ask that user to log in with the `manage_pages` permission if you're planning on performing admin-specific actions on the page.

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl(['manage_pages']) . '">Login</a>';
```

### Extending User Access Token

By default, you'll get a short-lived user access token from Facebook. I'm assuming you're using a database to store your access tokens. You'll need to exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived user access token and save the new token in the database.

```
$accessToken = $session->getAccessToken();
$longLivedAccessToken = $accessToken->extend();
echo (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
```

### Using a code

If you're storing the long-lived user access token in the database, as a best practice, you should use the token to generate a `code` and then generate another long-lived access token. This way you're not using the same access token for all the requests on behalf of the user every time. This minimizes the chances of your app being flagged as spam.

```
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;

$longLivedAccessToken = new AccessToken('{long-lived-access-token}');
$code = AccessToken::getCodeFromAccessToken($longLivedAccessToken);
$newLongLivedAccessToken = AccessToken::getAccessTokenFromCode($code);
```

## Page Access Tokens

If you want to post statues on the page and have the posts appear as if the page had posted the statuses you'll need to use a page access token.

### Obtaining a page access token

Using a page admin's long-lived user access token, you can list the pages that that user administrates on the [`/me/accounts` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/accounts/). You'll want to pull the `access_token` field which is the page access token. You can also pull the `perms` field to see which [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#page_admin_roles) the admin user has.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/accounts?fields=name,access_token,perms');
$pageList = $request->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

### Short-lived vs Long-lived page access tokens

If you use a short-lived user access token to obtain a page access token, the page access token will also be short-lived.

You could exchange the short-lived page access token with a long-lived page access token directly if you wanted to. This would give you a page access token that would last about 2 months.

```
$pageAccessToken = new AccessToken('{short-lived-page-access-token}');
$longLivedPageAccessToken = $pageAccessToken->extend();
```

However, if you use a long-lived user access token to obtain the page access token, the page access token will **never expire**.

### Page access tokens "gotcha"

You can think of page access tokens as "sub access tokens" to the page admin user access token. This is an important concept because page access tokens are associated with the admin user you obtained the page access token from.

Since there are [different page admin roles](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#page_admin_roles) that a page admin can have, that will limit the scope of the page access token if the admin user isn't assigned the role that grants them a specific permission you need.

Comment: Nice answer. But how to differentiate long-lived token from short-lived token, such that if long-lived token is used, I don't have to extend it?

Comment: There are two ways to distinguish long-lived and short-lived access tokens: 1) by examining the `expires_in` or `expires` metadata when you initially receive the access token. 2) By sending the token to the [`/debug_token` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/debug_token) and examining the access token metadata.

Comment: with `/debug_token` endpoint, I receive `expires_at` = 0 , which means never-expired ? quite strange, as I extend the token once with code only.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the PHP SDK for this, you can do this easily with CURL. See this article for a detailed description with all the code you need: http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

If you really want to do this with the PHP SDK, there is an easy solution explained here: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

You just need to call a specific function on the FacecookSession object:

```
$facebookSession->getLongLivedSession();
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/PAGE-ID?fields=access_token');
```

Btw, there is no "Page-specific User Token", but of course you need to authorize the User with the "manage_pages" permission to get access to /me/accounts - so you can get a list of the administrated Pages with all their Access Tokens. After you get that list, the only difference is that you will get a short-living Page Token with a short-living User Token and an extended one with an extended User Token.

Comment: Hi Luschn, The blog is good and I managed to get it working, but I would rather choose to use the SDK where possible. If no one answers with an SDK related answer soon, I'll vote up your anwser

Comment: i´ve added some more information, about how to use the php sdk :)

Comment: if you downvote something, please explain why so we can improve. my answer is definitely correct, it just may not be valid for newer versions of the php sdk anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code PHP

```html
<?php
session_start();
require '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($config['app_id'], $config['app_secret']);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/folder/index.php');

try {
 $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

 if ($session):
  $_SESSION['facebook'] = $session->getToken();
  header('Location: index.php');
 endif;

 if (isset($_SESSION['facebook'])):
  $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['facebook']);
  $page_id = '000000000000';
  // get page access token
  $access_token = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/' . $page_id,  array( 'fields' => 'access_token' ) ))
    ->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
 
   // save access token in variable for later use  
  $access_token = $access_token['access_token'];
  
  $page_post = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/'. $page_id .'/feed', array(
      'access_token' => $access_token,
      'name' => 'TITULO DEL ENLACE',
      'link' => 'http://www.example.com/',
      'caption' = 'Example text',
      'message' => 'This is my link!',
  ) ));
  $response = $page_post->execute();
  $graphObjectClass = $response->getGraphObject();
  $facebook_POST = $graphObjectClass;
 endif;
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
  echo $ex;
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo $ex;
}
?>
```

Comment: Mind to explain a bit?

Comment: You should provide explanation of the codes you provided.